# Page publishing gets stuck on "Rendering" step

Tags: publishing, transport

**Background**. We have 2 independent servers both running Tridion. Until recently we used one of them (PROD Tridion) for production and the other one (TEST Tridion) to publish the content to the local environments. We have now decided to retire TEST Tridion and instead create another publication on PROD Tridion which will be used for testing purposes.

**Issue.** While we can still successfully publish to our prod servers, it fails if we attempt to publish to our local test environment. No errors or exceptions in the cd_transport, cd_core, or cd_deployer log files.

When looking at the "Tridion.ContentManager.Publisher" log file the last output before it hangs is "Writing file: `c:\Temp\tcm_0-1816713-66560.Content\Pages\blabla\blabla.xhtml"`. Nothing happens after that.

However, if we simply restart the Tridion CMS, the page that has been in the queue gets published without us doing anything.

What could be the issue here and why does it work if we restart Tridion?

Comment: What version of SDL are you using and what is the publishing model you have setup (legacy or topology)? If you are using TPM, how have you setup your TPM configurations (with or without ODATA)?

Comment: "Rendering" suggests templating, but the file hanging might mean there is likely a difference beween PROD (I guess that's your "Live" environment) and TEST. See @TannerBrine's [post](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/when-virus-scanning-goes-wrong) and comments in case the issue might be related to virus scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps it may help you to resolve issue:

- check your template using template builder to verify that it works sometimes it may cause the renderer to hang.
- If you are using a custom resolver check that code too it may also cause the publisher to hang.
- try to increase the no of rendering and deploying threads in the SDL web MMC snap-in

Comment: Thanks for the tips! We have 8 rendering and deploying threads on our prod tridion and everything seems to be working fine when we publish to stage and prod, the only case this issue occurs is when we attempt to publish to our local environment (we use an ssh tunnel to achieve that).

What concerns me is that if I add a page to the publishing queue and it hangs a simple restart would solve the problem. Is there any interaction with the DB at a `rendering` step that could cause this to happen? or maybe something else that could affect the rendering and not trigger the transport step?

Comment: usually rendering stuck in some cases if you publish the same items multiple times and check any event system code is implemented in your application. Depending on your application are you trying to fetch anything from the database.  Failing at transport phase usually happens due to the configuration issues like size of the package being pushed is too large, check the sender and receiver elements in cd_transport_config file.